# JPA CascadeType.REMOVE inverse

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a db with Customers and Bookings. Each booking has 1 customer, and a customer can have many bookings. So I have a @ManyToOne relationship annotated on the customer member. I want if I delete the customer, the booking will be deleted also. But I'm only able to do it the other way, if the Booking is delete, the Customer is deleted, I dont want that. Here is my code:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Customer.FIND_ALL, query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c ORDER BY c.name ASC"),
    @NamedQuery(name = Customer.FIND_BY_EMAIL, query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.email = :email")
})
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "customer", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
public class Customer  implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final String FIND_ALL = "Customer.findAll";
public static final String FIND_BY_EMAIL = "Customer.findByEmail";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z\\s]+")
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;



@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Booking.FIND_ALL, query = "SELECT b FROM Booking b ORDER BY b.bookingDate ASC")
})
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "booking", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"customer", "booking_date"}))
public class Booking implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

public static final String FIND_ALL = "Booking.findAll";


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;


@NotNull
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(name = "customer")
private Customer customer;

@NotNull
@Future(message = "Bookings must be in future")
@Column(name = "booking_date")
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
private Date bookingDate;
```

So if I delete the Customer, the booking should also be deleted. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Remove cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE} from the ManyToOne, and add it to the inverse OneToMany side of the association.

Comment: Where should I put it as there is no Booking member in Customer. Does there have to be a List of Bookings in Customer ?

Comment: Yes. A Set<Booking> would be a better choice. Read the hibernate documentation about bidirectional OneToMany associations.

Comment: Many thanks, got it working now. I'll post the answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nizet for the tips. It's working now with the code below.

```
/* Booking class */
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customer")
private Customer customer;


/* Customer class */
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy = "taxi")
private Set<Booking> bookings = new HashSet<Booking>();;
```